# Does Bertrand's Postulate give us the tightest proven upper bound for prime gaps?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

[Bertrand's Postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) asserts that there is a prime between $n$ and $2n$.

Is this the best such upper bound on prime gaps known today, or have  stronger estimates been proved? I mean results of the kind:

- there will always be a prime between $n$ and $2n-2$, or
- there will always be a prime between $n$ and $cn$ with $1<c<2$?

Was any such improvement proved rigorously, or is Bertrand's Postulate still the best we have?

Comment: You can read [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate). There is no reason to ask such a question here.

Comment: There is a nice proof of this from the book "Proofs from the book", which is elementary and you might like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. See theorem 3 of:

O. Ramar´e, Y. Saouter, Short effective intervals containing primes, J. Number Theory 98 (2003),
no. 1.

A related statement states for all $\epsilon > 0$, for sufficiently large $n$, there is a prime between $n, (1+ \epsilon)n$ which is a trivial corollary of the PNT.

For your first question, both of those statements have been proven.

Comment: "sufficiently large" makes this a non-generalisation of Bertrands postulate.

Comment: What about my second question? All known primes gaps have been observed to be smaller than n or n-2, with maybe the exception of the largest known prime.

Comment: Have you looked at the reference? And what do you mean by "with maybe the exception of the largest known prime"?

Comment: @MayankPandey From the largest known prime to the next prime, what is the distance? Let k be the largest known prime. Let u be the next consecutive prime, which is currently unknown. Will u be only slightly less than 2k?

Comment: I should have said that all known prime gaps are significantly smaller than that which is allowed by Bertrand's postulate. However, we do not know concerning any prime gaps following the largest known prime as to whether they will be as large as Bertrand's postulate will allow or if Legendre's conjecture will hold true.

Comment: @JeffreyYoung: Far from it. The next prime is at most 1.000000000000000025k (Dusart 2010), and probably a lot closer than that. Apparently the result of Baker-Harman-Pintz could be made effective and that would give a much better gap, more like $(1+10^{-9148214})k$, but we don't have that yet. And far better is conjectured, more like $(1+3.11\cdot10^{-17425155})k$.